# Sequence of numbers....is there a shorter way to do this?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is the exercise:

**The sequence of numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3 \dots a_n \dots$ is defined as $a_n = \frac 1{n+1} - \frac 1{n+2}$, for each integer $n\ge 1$. What is the sum of the first 15 terms of this sequence?**

Plugging in takes too long. Is there a shorter way to do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that $$a_n=\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2}\;?$$ If so, write out the first three or four terms (instead of $15$) and look for things that cancel out.

Comment: I have edited in accordance with @BrianM.Scott's comment, and if this is wrong let me know.  If this is right, try what Brian suggests. Don't simplify first, just start writing everything out.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial sum telescopes.

$$ a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_{14} + a_{15} = \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4}\right) + \cdots + \left(\frac{1}{15} - \frac{1}{16}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{16} - \frac{1}{17}\right) $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3}\right) + \cdots + \left(\frac{1}{16} - \frac{1}{16}\right) - \frac{1}{17}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{17} = \boxed{\frac{15}{34}}.$$

Comment: Many thanks....